# Older Facebook App broke a few weeks ago (end of October). Did something change?

Tags: facebook, fbml

My Game of Go on Facebook (http://apps.facebook.com/gothegame/) seems to have died. When I go to the app page, it's blank.

It had been up and running for a few years, with a few hundred active users playing games daily. Looking at my db, I can see lots of activity up until 10/19. Then nothing.

Any idea what changed around then?

Comment: It's just hard to guess the problem. Did you check your canvas page?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the old fb_sig style authentication then your application would have broken the other day.

Mine did this without any notification from Facebook. I had to rewrite the authentication to use the new signed_request authentication method.

Comment: If this is what happened, here's a handy guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/ it links to the docs and the blog posts which mentioned this between May 2011 and now

Answer (score 2):

Facebook API changes from time to time. Read their developer blog at least once a week.

They DID change things , frequently .